# I wrote a bin_search with STL, but these is a small BUG

Tags: c++

these is no problems in function generate, and getData
while debug bin_search()  the program failed

it seems like that in function bin_search,
using a invalid iterator to the vector

debug in VS2015, find out the in main() function , after bin_search()

value of pos still unknow.

I don't know how to figure it

```
#include<iostream>

#include <cstdio>

#include <fstream>

#include <ctime>

#include <cstdlib>

#include <vector>
using namespace std;
using RANK = vector<int>::iterator;
const int RANGE = 1000;
const int SIZE = 50;
void generate(ofstream& of) {
    srand(static_cast<unsigned> (time(nullptr)));
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i)
        of << static_cast<int> (rand() % RANGE) << endl;
}
void getData(ifstream& ifs, vector<int> &v) {
    int tmp;
    while(ifs >> tmp)
        v.push_back(tmp);
}
RANK bin_search(vector<int> &v, int key, RANK low, RANK high) {
    RANK e = v.end();
    // if (*mid == key)
    //     return mid;
    // else if (*mid < key)`
    //     bin_search(v, key, low, mid);
    // else if (*mid > high)
    //     bin_search(v, key, ++mid, high);
    // return nullptr;
    while (low < high) {
        RANK mid = v.begin() + v.size() / 2;
        if (*mid == key)
            return mid;
        else if (*mid < key) 
            low = mid;
        else if (*mid > key)
            high = ++mid;
    }
    return e;
} 
int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    ofstream ofs("data", ios::out);
    generate(ofs);
    vector<int> arr;
    ifstream ifs("data", ios::in);
    getData(ifs, arr);
    int value;
    cout << "pls enter num to find: " << endl;
    cin >> value;
    RANK pos = bin_search(arr, value, arr.begin(), arr.end());
    cout << *pos << endl;
    // if (pos == arr.end())
    //     cout << "data " << value << "not find." << endl;
    // else {
    //     cout << "data at " << distance(arr.begin(), pos) << endl;
    // }
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you try stepping into your code with a debugger?

Comment: Dereferencing `pos` without checking if it is valid is UB if no element has been found. The key to the problem is West's answers. You need a sorted array to begin with for a binary search.

Answer (score 1):

How do you know the array is sorted before you apply binary search? All arrays must be sorted before doing binary search.

```
void generate(ofstream& of) {
  srand(static_cast<unsigned> (time(nullptr)));
  for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i)
    of << static_cast<int> (rand() % RANGE) << endl;
}
```

In this function you generate a series of random numbers which you then attemp to apply binary search to that array. Binary search works by doing a logarithmic series of comparisons on a sorted array of numbers to find the item in the array or to say the item cannot be found (or between which numbers it would exist if it could be found).

If the array is unsorted, as it appears to be in this case because the numbers in the array are generated by `srand` and even it is not that bad at generating random numbers, the binary search's invariant is never met and the best we can do is searching linearly through the array.